# Wordpress - get page id in menu filter

Tags: wordpress, menu, filter

I am using a filter for the menu and would need to get the ID of the pages in the menu.
This is what I have:

Menu filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'custom_menu_function', 10, 2 );
```

Then the filter functions starts like this:

```
function custom_menu_function ( $items, $args ) {

 $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $dom->loadHTML($items);

        $linkNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        $classes= $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

        $count = $linkNodes->length;       

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

          How to get the page id's here for each menu item, 
          not the id that the menu item has?

        }

}
```

So if I have created page Test that has id=2 and I have tbhis item in the menu. How to get it's id(2) in the menu filter above?

Am I missing some basic thing?

Tnx.

Comment: Can you use a custom walker? Because with this technique you can do a replace on the `id` attribute of each item(note that it's the `li`'s that have the id usually) and extract the ID from there, but you can't completely rely on this.

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I am just a little bit familiar with the walker, so if I could get the id in the filter function it would beb much better. If walker is the only option, is there a way(must be just don't see it) to get the menu item type as well. Let's say I have the id, can I then sort if item is a page, categoriy, post, ..? Just getting the regular type will always give me page I think.

Comment: Custom walker should be the best option then. Just define a new class like so: `class MyCustomMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu` and copy the `start_el()` function from [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L67). In this function, you will have access to the `$item` variable - do a `var_dump()` to it and you'll see it's contents. `$item->object_id` - this is the ID of the page/post/category/etc.